# Haskell Blackjack game

Tags: haskell

Hi i'm having problems summing my hand up since an Ace can be 1 or 11. How can I make a function which takes in a hand, ie [Card] and calculates the total value?

Here is what I have so far:

```
handValue :: [Card]->[Int]
handValue [] = 0
handValue (x:xs) = sum((val x)++([handValue xs]))
```

where val is already defined and returns from a card an array of values. eg val ("Ace","Hearts") gives [1,11] val ("Five","Hearts") gives [5]

Any pointers would be appreciated.

edit: after duplodes suggestion I have this:

```
    handValue :: [Card]->[Int]
handValue [] = 0
handValue (x:xs) = 
            if (val x ==[1,11])
            then    (map sum (sequence [[1,11], handValue xs]))
                else [ sum [(val x)]++([handValue xs])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond fixing your function you should pay attention to why it didn't work in first place. Firstly, the type you gave is

```
handValue :: [Card] -> [Int]
```

but your recursive definition has single values, and not lists, as result types (the `0` literal in the first equation; the use of `sum`, which is `Num a => [a] -> a` in the second one).

Now, assuming the type was changed to `[Card] -> Int`, your definition would be legal, but the results would be weird. Your second equation is:

```
handValue (x:xs) = sum((val x)++([handValue xs]))
```

What happens if `x` is an ace? `val x` will be `[1, 11]`, and so *both* values will be concatenated and included in the sum. In effect, your aces now count not as 1 or 11, but 12 points! n.m's solution, which I paraphrase here as

```
Prelude> map sum . sequence $ [[1,11], [5], [6]]
[12,22]
```

skirts around the problem by generating lists of values for all possible choices of aces (`sequence`) and summing all possibilities separately (`map sum`), resulting in a list of values (as in the signature you had originally given). That, however, does not quite settle the issue, as you will eventually need to decide for one of the possibilities. And now we likely have enough material for a different question, once you get to that point...

Comment: It is a mechanical choice whether to treat an ace as 1 or 11: Treat it as 11, unless the total score would be over 21 by doing so.  There is no need for the user to pick.  IOW, I think n.m.'s solution is a good approach (if only someone would explain why it works).

Comment: My ignorance of card games has shown up... In any case, that means that there should be either an automatic decision accounting for the partial sum of the hand or a way of picking the largest sum less or equal to 21 from n.m's solution.

Comment: @duplode I can't see how to use that in my example. I've editted my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
Prelude Control.Monad> liftM sum . sequence $ [[1,11], [5], [6]]
[12,22]
```

Comment: Why what? Why does it work? Why does it belong? Why post an answer and spoil the fun?

Comment: @n.m. I understand to use sequence but I can't get it working, see my example.

Comment: @John `liftM sum . sequence . map val` should give you a list of possible hand values.